# Scrapy Python response.css loop

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to loop every offer on this website:

```
https://www.tui.pl/wypoczynek/wyniki-wyszukiwania-samolot?pm_source=SG&pm_name=LSC&q=:price:byPlane:T:a:WAW:dF:6:dT:8:startDate:15.09.2018:endDate:30.09.2018:ctAdult:2:ctChild:0:tripType:WS&fullPrice=false
```

Code:

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield SplashRequest(
        url = 'https://www.tui.pl/wypoczynek/wyniki-wyszukiwania-samolot?pm_source=SG&pm_name=LSC&q=:price:byPlane:T:a:WAW:dF:6:dT:8:startDate:15.09.2018:endDate:30.09.2018:ctAdult:2:ctChild:0:amountRange:defaultAmountRange:minHotelCategory:defaultHotelCategory:tripAdvisorRating:defaultTripAdvisorRating:beach_distance:defaultBeachDistance:tripType:WS&fullPrice=false&page=0',
        args={'wait': 5.0}
    )

def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.css('div#offerPage'):
       print(item.css('div#offerPage h3 a ::text').extract())
```

output:

```
['TUI MAGIC LIFE Waterworld', 'Riu Bambu', 'Ivana Palace', 'Kos Bay', 'Tia Maria', 'Rezydencja Villa List', 'Esperanto', 'Jupiter', 'Vezhen', 'Obzor Beach Resort', 'Palma', 'Victoria Palace', 'Chaika Beach', 'Fenix Beach', 'Globus', 'Erma', 'Sunset Resort', 'Palace', 'Trakia Garden', 'Perla Sun', 'Lilia', 'Poseidon', 'Garden of Eden', 'Park Hotel Continental', 'Hotel Karolina', 'Santa Marina Holiday Village', 'Semeli Hotel', 'Delfin', 'Lion Sunny Beach', 'Selena Beach', 'Mercury']
```

Looks like my output is in the one list. How can I change the loop every `#offerPage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scrapy selector docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html). You're using css so we'll stick with that.

The `reponse.css()` selection is yielding a single element list, because there is only one `#offerPage` (id's are unique). So you're `for` loop in `parse()` is only executing once, but the selector in it is yielding a list with many elements, because there are many `h3 > a` elements in your first selection.

You should drill into the elements one more level so that the `response.css()` yields more than one element for your `parse()` loop. Then iterate through.

```
def parse(self, response):

  # get list
  list = response.css('div#offerPage h3')

  #iterate over list
  for item in list:
    print(item.css('a::text').extract())
```

Comment: I've got an error:
    print(item.css('a::text').extract())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'css'

Comment: Edited my answer. `extract()` should be called in the loop, not the original selection

Comment: It works well now! Many thanks!! Do you have any docs wher I can read more about selecting correct css elements?

Comment: Also, is there a way, that I can loop for entire row element, so I will be able to access price and other info or would I need to create new loop?

Comment: @luuu If the price and other values are within the `div#offerPage > h3` element or are in its children, then you can access them in the same loop.